# IIS not find angular request header

Tags: angular, iis, request-headers

My IIS cannot get requestHeader from angular.
**I found similar questions but no one of them has good answer, so please not indicate as duplicate question.**

Here is my angular code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomHttpService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  get(url:string,userName:any, password:any):Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({'username':userName, 'Password':password});
    return this.http.get('https://localhost:44345/api/'+url, {headers});
  }
  //other code...
          }
```

Here is the code at C#:

```
    public class ResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    async protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage>
SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        try
        {

            var b = request.Headers.GetValues("username").FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle exception...
        }
        try
        {

            var c = request.Headers.GetValues("Password").FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle exception...
        }
        HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        return response;
    }
}
```

At C# side I get an exception - title not found.
What can be the problem?

Comment: Check network tabs in your browser and see if the header is sent. If yes, then your issue is on server end. Also, what's `title` ?

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that you have already applied the DelegateHandler to the request pipeline properly.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MessageHandler2());


        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

The most possibility is that Enabling the CORS feature interfered with the Http headers added from the frontend. Provided that you just check the error on the server-side, try to check the client-side error displayed in the browser. It might have a below error,

> Request header field username is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Take the IIS CORS module(an extension to solve CORS issue in IIS)  as an example, 
After installing the IIS CORS, we have to adding some exceptions,

```
<system.webServer>
    <cors enabled="true">
      <add origin="*">
<allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true" />
</add>
    </cors>
```

Then the `Http Headers` works properly.
[image]
**App.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my angular';
  data='';
  private url="https://vabqia593vm:8734/api/values"
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ){
  }
  getData():Observable<string>{
    return this.http.get<string>(this.url,{responseType:'json'});
  }
ngOnInit(){
    let myheaders = new HttpHeaders({'username':"Abraham", 'Password':"123456"});
    this.http.get(this.url, {headers:myheaders,responseType:"text"}).subscribe((res:any)=>{
      console.log(res);
      this.data=res;
    })
}
}
```

**MessageHandler.**

```
    public class MessageHandler2 : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
  HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in request.Headers)
        {
            sb.Append(item.Key.ToString()+" : "+item.Value.FirstOrDefault()+"\n");
        }

        // Create the response.
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(sb.ToString())
        };

        var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
        tsc.SetResult(response);   // Also sets the task state to "RanToCompletion"
        return tsc.Task;
    }
}
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.